# Split client and server - meteorjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am using latest version of Meteor.

As you know Meteor wants to keep everything inside same directory.

Like:

```
MeteorProject
   -- .meteor
   -- client
   -- imports
   -- server
   -- test
   -- node_modules
   -- package.json
```

I have create a public repo with a very simple reproduction scenario:

https://bitbucket.org/hassansardarbangash/meteor-react-boiler

What I need is that I want host server and client on separate server machines, since this is the most viable approach to have a good architecture.

Or may be I want to host admin panel client side on separate server, so here I have 3 separate services.

There is also a possibility that I want to create 3 more Reactjs based applications, and I would like to use same meteor server for all the transactions or api calls etc.

So is there any possibility how can I separate client and server in Meteorjs?

Comment: This case is similar: https://forums.meteor.com/t/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-new-front-end-app-to-an-existing-meteor-server/53764

Comment: @RicardoAragão the problem with that topic is that they are all suggesting 3rd party ddp client libraries, which cannot be trusted and there were several libraries that go deprecated and unmaintained now. So i need something that is natively supported by meteor community

Comment: You can look this https://dev.to/jankapunkt/microservices-with-meteor-40la to get some ideas too. I don't believe you will find anything ready to use.

Comment: Then, you can have the same code base, but in deploy, you can just "enable" the front or server and manually put the DDP connection on the client manually.

Comment: @RicardoAragão but how can I change the ddp connection?

Comment: Look at the topic *Create the shop app* in the link I sent you before ( dev.to/jankapunkt/microservices-with-meteor-40la ). The author shows how to do it.

Comment: have you considered using a headless CMS like Directus or strapi? this way, you would only need to build frontend and have a professional backend to support it

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Meteor.isServer` and `Meteor.isClient` to specify code that should run on the server or the client.
Something like

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('users', function() {
    ...
  });
}
```